# How to click on a link in an inactiveTab?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am building a webscraper based on Python 3, Selenium (Firefox) and BeautifulSup, so I am interested only in Python support.

In this section of html I want to click on the ***Execute Script*** button.
[html code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te821.jpg)

I am able to read the page source, but it looks like when I call:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="menu_link_-481524888_1374656230"]').click()`

I receive this **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-92-dd92f6ed1ddc>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="menu_link_-481524888_1374656230"]').click()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a id="menu_link_-481524888_1374656230" href="javascript:window.location=getPath()+"/ForwardAction.do?modulo=proposta&path=/SelecionarConvenio/SelecionarConvenio.do?destino=ListarContratos""> could not be scrolled into view
```

I looked on internet I realized the tab is *inactive*, since there is an attribute `inactiveTab`. If I manually click, the site runs fine. So, how do I access a button under and inactive tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `inactiveTab` should affect our element in question. Could you try this and let me know if it works:

```
Element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="menu_link_-481524888_1374656230"]')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", Element)
```

This will execute JavaScript to interact with the button.

Comment: @Marcelo, if you could accept the edit I suggested as well, it formats your question.

Comment: I liked a lot your suggestion. How do I accept it? Sorry, I am newbie to SO.

Comment: I have marked, but it looks like I my score is yet too low to add my point to you as visible.

Comment: @Marcelo, Yes, you don't have enough rep yet to upvote, but I believe you can accept an answer still by checking on the mark next to the correct answer, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Marcelo, Welcome to SO!